# Rate of change problem involving trigonometry

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry, related-rates

[image]

> A and B are $100$ m apart. A runner R runs at a speed of 6 m/s from A to B. Given that $BC = 50$ m and $\angle CBA = \frac{\pi}{3}$. Let $BR$ = $x$ m and $\angle BCR = \theta$. Find the rate of change of $\theta$ when $R$ is $60$ m away from $A$.

Sine law shows:

$$x = \frac{50\sin\theta}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{3} + \theta)} $$

then
\begin{align}
\frac{d\theta}{dt} 
&= \frac{dx}{dt}\frac{d\theta}{dx} \\
&= -6 \cdot \frac{\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{3} + \theta)}{25\sqrt{3}}
\end{align}
Also,
$$40 = \frac{50\sin\theta_0}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{3} + \theta_0)}$$
but I couldn't find the exact value of $\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{3} + \theta_0)$ from this. How should I proceed? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $$\dfrac{\sin (60+\alpha)}{\sin \alpha}=\dfrac{5}{4}$$

$$\dfrac{\sin 60 \cos \alpha+\cos 60 \sin \alpha}{\sin \alpha}=\dfrac{5}{4}$$

$$\Rightarrow \cot \alpha = \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

$$\Rightarrow \sin \alpha = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+\cot ^2 \alpha}}=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt 7}$$

$$\therefore \sin (60+\alpha) = \dfrac{5}{4} \cdot \dfrac{2}{\sqrt 7}$$